# DataTrigger Binding in Button not reflected on value change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a button whose visibility would change based on the bonded value. Here's my code

```
        <Button Content="Click Me" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isShow, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isShow, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

```
public bool isShow { get; set; }       
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.isShow = !this.isShow;
}
```

I'm a beginner in C# and getting used to data bindings. Please let me know where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the setter of the `isShow` property for the `Visibility` to get refreshed whenever the source property is set to a new value dynamically:

```
public class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    private bool _isShow;
    public bool isShow
    {
        get { return _isShow; }
        set { _isShow = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.isShow = !this.isShow;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You may also remove one of the triggers:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isShow, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```